Skipping auto-scroll behavior due to `position: sticky` or `position: fixed` css
I'm getting a warning like this in the console. when coding Nextjs
my code
  <aside className={`site-off desktop-hide ${showMenu ? "show-menu" : ""}`}>
....
</aside>


css
.site-off {
    position: fixed;
    width: 320px;
    height: var(--percent100);
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.4s, visibility 0.4s;
    will-change: transform, visibility;
}


You'll not providing enough information. In what circumstances will this error message pop up? Try to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Related: Why is it that NextJS cannot auto-scroll when there are fixed elements on the page?, Dialog open warning in latest nextjs version: 13.4.19

Wrapping the concerned element with a div seems to fix the issue:
<div>
    <aside className={`site-off desktop-hide ${showMenu ? "show-menu" : ""}`}>
      ....
    </aside>
</div>

More info here: https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/1355#issuecomment-1867533627
